# the output of this code must be john james and rose.but j o h appears at the output.why?

Tags: javascript

```js
var name = ["john", "james", "rose"];
var ul = document.getElementById('name-list');
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var span = document.createElement('li');
    span.textContent = name[i];
    ul.appendChild(span);
}
```

```html
<ul id="name-list"></ul>
```

the output of this code must be john james and rose.but j o h appears at the output.why??

Comment: I think there is something missing from this snippet. Based on the code you provided, it works as expected when i copy / pasted into https://jsfiddle.net/naveedn/ozmkru9x/. I think in your actual code, you might be attempting to do this operation on the first element of the array, which is a string. That would be the only reason why the first three characters of the first element in the array are getting printed. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use the word `name` as a variable, which is [a reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).

If you change your variable (to say, `names`), then your function works as expected:

```js
var names = ["john", "james", "rose"];
var ul = document.getElementById('name-list');
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement('li');
  span.textContent = names[i];
  ul.appendChild(span);
}
```

```html
<ul id="name-list"></ul>
```